# Regex doesn't match, greediness

Tags: php, regex, regex-greedy

I try to match two parts in a string with a regex in PHP. There is a problem with the greediness, I think. I would like the first regex (see comment) to give me the first two captures, as the second regex, but still capture both strings. What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to get `+123` (if `cd:` exists, as in first string) and `456`.

```
<?php

$data[] = 'longstring start waste cd:+123yz456z longstring';
$data[] = 'longstring start waste +yz456z longstring';
$regexs[] = '/start[^z]*?(cd:([^y]+)y)?[^z]*z([^z]*)z/'; // first
$regexs[] = '/start[^z]*?(cd:([^y]+)y)[^z]*z([^z]*)z/';  // second

foreach ($regexs as $regex) {
  foreach ($data as $string) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $string, $match)) {
      echo "Tried '$regex' on '$string' and got " . implode(',', array_split($match, 1));
      echo "\n";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Output is:

```
Tried '/start[^z]*?(cd:([^y]+)y)?[^z]*z([^z]*)z/' on 'longstring start waste cd:+123yz456z longstring' and got ,,456
Tried '/start[^z]*?(cd:([^y]+)y)?[^z]*z([^z]*)z/' on 'longstring start waste +yz456z longstring' and got ,,456
Tried '/start[^z]*?(cd:([^y]+)y)[^z]*z([^z]*)z/' on 'longstring start waste cd:+123yz456z longstring' and got cd:+123y,+123,456
```

There is no fourth line since `cd:` is not present in the second string.

Expected output (since I'm no expert), where the first line differs from actual output:

```
Tried '/start[^z]*?(cd:([^y]+)y)?[^z]*z([^z]*)z/' on 'longstring start waste cd:+123yz456z longstring' and got cd:+123y,+123,456
Tried '/start[^z]*?(cd:([^y]+)y)?[^z]*z([^z]*)z/' on 'longstring start waste +yz456z longstring' and got ,,456
Tried '/start[^z]*?(cd:([^y]+)y)[^z]*z([^z]*)z/' on 'longstring start waste cd:+123yz456z longstring' and got cd:+123y,+123,456
```

Comment: looks like you forgot a line of output.

Comment: Also, could you explain in words what you are trying to capture? It's not very obvious.

Comment: @Chriszuma The second regex doesn't match the second string because `cd:` is not present in that string.

Comment: @Chriszuma Have now tried to clarify what I want: I'm trying to get `+123` (if `cd:` exists, as in first string) and `456`.

Comment: Could you clarify the question, especially the sentence with "...as the second regex...". Just write expected outcome of the logging for example. And why is there only three lines in output?

Comment: @Lycha Sorry for not having clarified what I wanted to do. I tried again by adding expected output. The fourth line is missing since `cd:` is not present in the second string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you want to capture `+123` if there is a `cd:`, and always `456`? Here's how I would do it:

```
$data[] = 'longstring start waste cd:+123yz456z longstring';
$data[] = 'longstring start waste +yz456z longstring';

$regexs[] = '/start.+?(?:cd:(.+?)y)?.*?z(.+?)z/';
```

With the liberal use of non-greedy (`?`) multipliers you can get it to do exactly what you want.

Also note the `(?:)` non-capture group. They are very useful.

**EDIT** Apparently that doesn't work, let's try a different approach, with an "either/or" group:

```
$regexs[] = '/start.+?(?:cd:(.+?)yz(.+?)z|\+yz(.+?)z)/';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying.
For your regex: `Tried '/start.+?(?:cd:(.+?)y)?.*?z(.+?)z/' on 'longstring start waste cd:+123yz456z longstring' and got ,456`
It seems as if it didn't capture `+123` by some unknown reason.

Comment: Thank you for the tip regarding `(?:)`. That was cool! (Didn't know it was possible.)

Comment: Okay, I don't see why that didn't work, but I edited my answer to try a different way.

Comment: @bloodphp did you try my new suggestion?